# vb.net if 30px away from screen border

Tags: vb.net

I have a resizable rectangle and also I have buttons that follow the bottom right side of it. But there is a problem, if the user re-sizes the box near the edge of the screen then the buttons will go off screen.

Although I've thought of a fix, and if the rectangle gets 32px close to the screens size then it moves the buttons [which will be above the line]. [Above the line is not the first option either].

I've tried using this code:
e.y, e.x = end of rectangle

```
If e.Y - 32 - = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height Then
  Label1.Text = "AboveLine"
Else
  Label1.Text = "OutsideLine"
End If
```

At the moment I only want 'Label1.text' to change.. but it only works for that [32px] which is only 1px. Instead I want it to be like a boundary and if the rectangle size hits between 32px away from the edge of the screen and to the edge of the screen then it'll move the button by

```
Me.Button1.Location = New Point(e.X - 46, e.Y + 1)
```

Heres an example of what I mean
[Image example](http://prntscr.com/3ahcfu)

Hopefully someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your after.

When the application is moved/dragged about, the 'Me.Move' event is fired

So what we are doing is checking the location of the right hand edge of the form, against the working area of the screen, the working area because that doesn't include the start bar, etc. And then the same with the bottom edge of the form

```
Private Sub Form1_Move(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
    If Me.Right > My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width - 32 Then
        Label1.Text = "Too far right, move button"
    End If

    If Me.Bottom > My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height - 32 Then
        Label1.Text = "Too far down, move button"
    End If
End Sub
```

Use More than signs instaed of an '=', it works all the way to the edge and not just on the 32nd pixel